# Space between menu items in Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am beginner web developer. I make project in Bootstrap 4.
I have small problem with to large space between menu items (top menu, nav)
I have this code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg text-body px-md-0 pb-md-0 navbar-light w-100">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="http://roelle.test/img/logo.jpg" class="pb-2"></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarmenu"
                        aria-controls="navbarmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarmenu">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <form class="mx-lg-5" action="" method="">
                            <div class="inner-addon rounded-0 navbar-search-form">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Szukaj produktu"
                                       aria-label="Szukaj produktu" name="query"/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown1" data-toggle="dropdown"
                               aria-haspopup="true"
                               aria-expanded="false">Kategorie <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">

                                                                                                            <div class="dropdown">
                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#"
                                               id="navbarDropdown1" role="button"
                                               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                               aria-expanded="false">Books <i
                                                    class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1">


                                                                                                                                                            <div class="dropdown">
                                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#"
                                                               id="navbarDropdown2" role="button"
                                                               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                                               aria-expanded="false">- Comic Book <i
                                                                    class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                                                            <div class="dropdown-menu"
                                                                 aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">


                                                                                                                                                                                                            <a class="dropdown-item"
                                                                           href="produkty/marvel-comic-book">- Marvel Comic Book</a>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                <div class="dropdown">
                                                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle"
                                                                               href="#"
                                                                               id="navbarDropdown4"
                                                                               role="button"
                                                                               data-toggle="dropdown"
                                                                               aria-haspopup="true"
                                                                               aria-expanded="false">- DC Comic Book
                                                                                <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                                                                            <div class="dropdown-menu"
                                                                                 aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown4">

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            <a class="dropdown-item"
                                                                                           href="produkty/computer-science">- Computer Science</a>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                <a class="dropdown-item"
                                                                           href="produkty/action-comics">- Action comics</a>
                                                                                                                                                                                                </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                <div class="dropdown">
                                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#"
                                                               id="navbarDropdown6" role="button"
                                                               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                                               aria-expanded="false">- Textbooks <i
                                                                    class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                                                            <div class="dropdown-menu"
                                                                 aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown6">


                                                                                                                                                                                                            <a class="dropdown-item"
                                                                           href="produkty/business">- Business</a>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                <a class="dropdown-item"
                                                                           href="produkty/finance">- Finance</a>
                                                                                                                                                                                                </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                                                                                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                                                                                                                                <div class="dropdown">
                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#"
                                               id="navbarDropdown10" role="button"
                                               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                               aria-expanded="false">Electronics <i
                                                    class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown10">


                                                                                                                                                            <div class="dropdown">
                                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#"
                                                               id="navbarDropdown11" role="button"
                                                               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                                               aria-expanded="false">- TV <i
                                                                    class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                                                            <div class="dropdown-menu"
                                                                 aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown11">


                                                                                                                                                                                                            <a class="dropdown-item"
                                                                           href="produkty/led">- LED</a>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                <a class="dropdown-item"
                                                                           href="produkty/blu-ray">- Blu-ray</a>
                                                                                                                                                                                                </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                <div class="dropdown">
                                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#"
                                                               id="navbarDropdown14" role="button"
                                                               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                                               aria-expanded="false">- Mobile <i
                                                                    class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                                                            <div class="dropdown-menu"
                                                                 aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown14">


                                                                                                                                                                                                            <a class="dropdown-item"
                                                                           href="produkty/samsung">- Samsung</a>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                <a class="dropdown-item"
                                                                           href="produkty/iphone">- iPhone</a>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                <a class="dropdown-item"
                                                                           href="produkty/xiomi">- Xiomi</a>
                                                                                                                                                                                                </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                                                                                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                                                                                                                                <a class="dropdown-item"
                                           href="produkty/no-1">no 1 </a>
                                                                                                                                                <a class="dropdown-item"
                                           href="produkty/no-1-disable">no 1 disable </a>
                                                                                                </div>
                        </li>


                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown2" data-toggle="dropdown"
                               aria-haspopup="true"
                               aria-expanded="false">Dla klienta <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/p/kontakt">Kontakt</a>
                                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/p/koszty-i-warunki-dostawy">Koszty i warunki dostawy</a>
                                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/p/o-nas">O nas</a>
                                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/p/polityka-prywatnosci">Polityka prywatności</a>
                                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/p/pomoc">Pomoc</a>
                                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/p/poradnik">Poradnik</a>
                                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/p/raty">Raty</a>
                                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/p/regulamin">Regulamin</a>
                                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/p/reklamacje-i-zwroty">Reklamacje i zwroty</a>
                                                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="http://roelle.test/kontakt">Kontakt</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        <li class="nav-item position-relative">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="http://roelle.test/koszyk"><img
                                    src="http://roelle.test/img/basket.jpg" class="pl-lg-4 pr-2">
                                <span
                                    class="badge badge-primary count">0</span>
                                <span class="d-lg-none d-xl-inline">Koszyk</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

$('.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
        if (!$(this).next().hasClass('show')) {
            $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').first().find('.show').removeClass("show");
        }
        var $subMenu = $(this).next(".dropdown-menu");
        $subMenu.toggleClass('show');

        $(this).parents('li.nav-item.dropdown.show').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
            $('.dropdown-submenu .show').removeClass("show");
        });

        return false;
    });
```

I have preview : http://serwer1356363.home.pl/_nauka/

Why after expanding Category => Books is there such a big gap between Books and Comic Books and then Comics and Marvel Comic Book?

How can I repair it?

Please help me

Comment: Can you create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with just enough code to reproduce the error, to simplify the problem down to the basics so we can see what is happening and to make it easier to find where the problem is.

Comment: Yes, look on http://serwer1356363.home.pl/_nauka/ - I make Iive preview my problem

Comment: That is not the way it works here. The question needs to include the minimum amount of code to reproduce the error so we can help. We are not expected to go through the entire code of your webpage to find the problem for you - tou are expected to do the work to narrow down the problem. You are looking for help, so you should at least help us to help you.

Comment: you could add this .dropdown-menu { margin: 0; padding: 0; } to fix the gap but this will give you some other problems though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Remove the line of code shown in the image.

And add the following to your css

```
.dropdown-menu { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

It should be fine now

[image]